# Wordpress save contenteditable div as postmeta form value

Tags: wordpress, innerhtml

So I have been making my own custom dropdown boxes. Using only divs tags and not input tags.

**Here is a snippit of the div that i outputted using javascript**

```
<div id="select_singledropdown" class="select_singledropdown" contenteditable="false" data-text="Search Here..." name="swp_schedule[0][swp_activity]" value="113 Aliens">113 Aliens</div>
```

The only issue is that when I go to save the field value in wordpress as postmeta. It can't seem to find the value like it does with an input tag.

**This code below works:**

```
<div class="swp_scheduler_time">Time: <input type="time" id="swp_starttime" name="swp_schedule[0][swp_starttime]" value="" >
```

As you can see from the code below wordpress picks up all values and adds them to the array swp_schedule[].

It then just saves the whole array to be picked up later.

**This is the wordpress code i use to save normal meta fields:**

```
$swpoldschedules = get_post_meta($post_id, $sprefix.'schedule', false);
if(isset($_POST['swp_schedule'])){
//print_r($_POST);
$swpschedules = $_POST['swp_schedule'];
}
if(isset($swpschedules)){
$serialize = serialize($swpschedules);  
$serialize = urlencode($serialize);
$post_id = $post_id;
$meta_key = $sprefix.'schedule';
$meta_value = $serialize;
//$prev_value = $swpoldschedules1;
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value /*$prev_value*/);
}
else {
$post_id = $post_id;
$meta_key = $sprefix.'schedule';
$meta_value = '';
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value /*$prev_value*/);
}
```

I even update my javascript code to

```
setattribute("value",value);
```

so that it appears very similar to an input box but without much luck.

So the only reason that my dropdown boxes use divs instead of inputboxes is so because alot of wordpress templates style input boxes which affects the layout of my dropdownboxes. Im trying to make this as compatable as possible.

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on posting a well-formatted first question. I would suggest you use a 'select' tag as per http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html and override the Wordpress template using CSS if necessary.

Comment: Great thankyou for your suggestion. However i can't use a select tag as this will create a normal html dropdown box. However in my custom dropdown box i just added a hidden input field which updates with the main div and can be interpreted by WordPress. Thank you for your help and feedback. it is really appreciated.

Comment: No worries, glad you got sorted. You might want to post your solution as an answer for the benefit of others with the same problem.